Improving Retake Strategies for Proof-Based Quiz Problems
Last year, I replaced homework entirely in my undergraduate courses (discrete mathematics, linear algebra, algorithms) because most students don't do it. The biggest complaint has been that quizzes are too stressful.
To address this, I allow students to retake a portion of quiz problems multiple times. However, with proof-based problems, students can simply memorize answers without understanding, which undermines the purpose of the quiz. It's also not always feasible to draft similar problems, especially if I asked for the proof of a particular result.
Currently, I decide randomly whether to keep the original problem or switch to a related but not necessarily similar one. The reason to do so is to encourage them to look at the problems on the same topic.
Is there a better way to handle this?

To answer some questions in the comment:

The quizzes account for 65% of the total grade.
I’ve replaced homework entirely with quizzes. Students receive a list of exercises to practice, and I select questions from these for the quizzes. I also include some proofs or exercises we've done in class.
Below is an example quiz question.


In a hidden labyrinth, there are 17 chambers connected by 129 secret passages. The labyrinth is dense and difficult to navigate, so travel is only possible along these passages.
A curious  wants to embark on a special journey:

Start at any chamber of its choice
Travel along the passages to visit every other chamber exactly once
Return to the starting chamber

Is it always possible for the  to complete this journey?
Prove that your answer is correct.

Saw some great advice on something like this (similar question), where the person said, he just wrote the quizzes using problems directly out off the text's drill problems.  No assigned graded HW, no suggested drill problems.  Just the kid's have an incentive to do the drill since they know the test problems will be similar (and identical, if they do all the drill).  Students love using old exam papers to study from.

Another good (previous advice) was to have several tests, maybe 10/semester.  And just let the kids drop worst one or one that they miss or have excuse not to be there.  Kind of takes away the work of retesting and the like.  And handles when the kid really does have an excuse for missing test time.  (I guess if they have two than they are SOL).

I think this is also a reasonable way to make the tests easy enough that you don't have huge pressure to curve or the like.  And after all, you should be using a text with reasonable problems (not ballbusters, not "projects").  And it's hard to complain that your tests are too hard if they are from the text.  (Don't only pick the hardest though. medium difficulty is best.)

@guesttroll This is pretty much what I am doing. I am just giving them an opportunity to avoid careless mistakes to impact too much on their grade.

Could you add some context to the question?

Are the quizzes for information only, pass/fail, or do they affect some grade and how?
What is the relationship of the homework to the quizzes?
Can you give some examples of what the quiz questions are like?`


How about giving them a different quiz on the same material, drawn from the same bank of homework questions, instead of a retake? Then keep the larger of the two scores.

I find that the more clarity I have about what I'm trying to measure/incentivize, the easier it is to design retakes (and also grade). If you want students to have a particular proof memorized, you should ask that proof again, and if you want them to demonstrate specific skills, identifying which skills you're testing makes finding alternatives easier.

@TomKern That is a good advice. If you can extend it to answer I will accept it.

Please assign homework. It is not for their grade. It is for their learning. They need to know how to learn the material, which requires you telling them good problems to work on. You can use https://www.myopenmath.com/ (free) to assign automatically graded homework. I've used it for linear and for discrete, and can make recommendations if asked.

I find that the more clarity I have about what I'm trying to measure, the easier it is to design retakes (and also grade).
If you're trying to measure if students know the proof of a specific important result, the retake should just be asking for that exact same proof again. In this case I consider it acceptable for students to memorize answers without understanding. The chunking (grouping bits together to make something easier to memorize) necessary to memorize a handful of proofs at once is already a good learning outcome. Plus the proof will continue to rattle around students' heads forming connections as they learn more. To make things fair between the retakes and original quiz, you can announce these problems in advance.
If you're trying to measure if students can solve a particular type of problem, try to identify what specific skills you're trying to measure. To do this, ask yourself how you plan on grading the question, and also ask what specific knowledge and skills your students will need to have in order to solve the problem. This should make finding alternatives for retakes easier.

I do and advocate the same but I also allow the students to "rehearse" the proofs with me before the exams. I normally let them present the proofs to me in writing or orally (their choice) and just either confirm that everything works, or pinpoint the first error or unclear place, explain what exactly is wrong or incomplete, and occasionally (but not always) give a hint on how to fix the issue. In small classes I allow checking the work during the exam with me (same rules, but no hints now). The side advantage is that they (and I) often know their grade by the moment they exit the exam room.
